# MATLAB - How to create output for each iteration of a looped calculation

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

This calculation aims to take a value (`a`) and perform one of two calculations on it for each iteration of a loop. Each sequential loop takes the new calculated value and recalculates it. I would like to keep the outputted value from each loop. Here is an example, using a logical array to decide which calculation to use over each of the 5 loops:

```
a = 0;
b = logical([1 0 1 1 0]);

for i = 1:length(b)
    if b(i) == 1
        a = 1*2 + a*2
    else
        a = a*3
    end
end
```

This example is not correct as it only returns 1 value for `a` rather than 5. The desired result from this example is:

```
a = 2 6 14 30 90
```

Please help me and amend anything else that is wrong here. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
a = [0];
b = logical([1 0 1 1 0]);

for i = 1:length(b)
    if b(i) == 1
        a(end+1) = 1*2 + a(end)*2;
    else
        a(end+1) = a(end)*3;
    end
end
```

Comment: A couple Matlab idiomatic items: `numel(b)` would be more appropriate than `length(b)`. typically you'd do `a(end+1) = a_next` instead of `a = [a, a_next]`. And it would be better to preallocate the output as `a = NaN([1 numel(b)+1]); a(1) = 0;` and then assign in to `a` using `a(i+1) = a_next`, to avoid inefficient  reallocations of the entire array on each pass of the loop.